# Automation of Web based SSH CLIENT PLUGIN script running using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, ssh, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to automate the following scenario:

I have installed a firefox plugin named FireSSH. Now, I have already manually and able to connect my remote server using the key and related parameters. I want to achieve the automation of this manual process of connecting to the remote client using selenium. As, selenium is used for web based automation, hence I have installed web browser based plugin to do SSH using web browser. The problem which I am facing is that I wanted to click on the "open menu" button on Firefox top right corner and within that dialogue I need to click the FireSSH plugin. It gives a prompt with all the credentials configured previously. I just need to click the connect button there and then I will get logged in as SSH client.

Further, I need to execute certain commands on this SSH client interface.

Kindly let me know, how to do that.

pls find the script which I am using but unable to do so.

```
package erewards2;

<imports ...>

public class putty_Connection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FirefoxDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();

        d1.get("chrome://firessh/content/firessh.xul#account=SIB2");

        d1.findElementByXPath("html/body/div[2]/div[25]").sendKeys("hello");
    }
}
```

getting below error

> : Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
>   [nsIWebNavigation.loadURI] Command duration or timeout: 212
>   milliseconds Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision: '3192d8a', time:
>   '2014-03-27 17:18:15' System info: host: 'pcs-PC', ip: '192.168.1.76',
>   os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.7.0_25' Session ID: c8915b04-23b3-455d-8e33-3bc72f886344 Driver
>   info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver Capabilities
>   [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox,
>   handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false,
>   locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true,
>   takesScreenshot=true, version=30.0}]  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:300)
>     at erewards2.putty_Connection.main(putty_Connection.java:44) Caused
>   by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException:
>   Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)
>   [nsIWebNavigation.loadURI] Build info: version: '2.41.0', revision:
>   '3192d8a', time: '2014-03-27 17:18:15' System info: host: 'pcs-PC',
>   ip: '192.168.1.76', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version:
>   '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_25' Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Comment: Is the plugin installed in the browser opened by your code?

Comment: no I am not able to access the plugin.

Comment: you cannot use plugins with webdriver

Comment: I am trying a new way...like if we can execute javascript using selenium webdriver and by the help of javascript we can somehow access the desired browser components..

Comment: try that, i am too bad at javascript :) .. let me know if you get success

Comment: sure...:) i also dont know javascript much. just basic tit bit..!

Answer (score 0):

@HarshNigam You are doing is correct but I will suggest this is **little long way and procedure based flow**.

**Working Solution :**

Why don't you give a deep dive using *PhantomJS*? I found it is **very helpful in SSH scenarios** when you wanted to connect instead of FF plugin.
I hope you will get better result with this. **All The Best !**

Comment: how will phantomjs help?  It's just another driver